# One computer, Two LAN adapter, Two IP's in same subnet with DHCP

Tags: linux, networking, dhcp, subnet

I have problems with networks. Troubles started when the ISP (Fiber) provided the same subnet for both lines. eth0 78.56.xxx.xxx  eth1 78.56.yyy.yyy

```
@:route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         78.56.255.254   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
78.56.192.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.192.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
78.56.192.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.192.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 lan1
172.22.22.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 lan1

@:ifconfig
eth0 inet addr:78.56.xxx.yyy  Bcast:78.56.255.255  Mask:255.255.192.0
eth1 inet addr:78.56.yyy.yyy  Bcast:78.56.255.255  Mask:255.255.192.0
```

Configuration (when it was old IP 85.206.YYY.YYY everything worked fine):

```
allow-hotplug eth0 
iface eth0 inet dhcp 

allow-hotplug eth1 
iface eth1 inet dhcp 
  post-up ip route add 78.56.192.0/18 dev eth1 src 78.56.yyy.yyy table eth1 
  post-up ip route add default via 78.56.255.254 dev eth1 table eth1 
  post-up ip rule add table eth1 from 78.56.yyy.yyy
```

And now there is a problem with DHCP renewal. When eth1 is run with ifup, everything works fine, but when renewal starts, line access is gone (ifdown eth1 && ifup eth1 and works well again until renewal)

```
 dhclient[2823]: message repeated 8 times: [ DHCPREQUEST of 78.56.225.235 on eth1 to 78.56.255.254 port 67 (xid=0x6fe207d3)]
```

dhcpdump:

```
eth0 
IP: 78.56.XXX.XXX (0:13:3b:f:48:e2) > 78.56.255.254 (0:0:5e:0:1:10) 
 eth1 
IP: 0.0.0.0 (0:13:3b:f:48:e1) > 255.255.255.255 (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
```

Is it possible to fix this trouble? Maybe what did I miss or did I do wrong?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65455/discussion-on-question-by-egidijus-one-computer-two-lan-adapter-two-ips-in-sa).